# Can re.search() skip past integer objects?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Question is pretty self-explanatory. I have a column in a pandas dataframe that contains both int and str objects. When I attempt to search it with re.search() it can't run because (I believe) some of the columns contain integer and it doesn't know what to do.

Is there some type of a way to fix this? I do not see an ignore errors argument.

Comment: Use a list comprehension that also checks type.  But before doing that you should re-evaluate your data representation decisions, and see if you can avoid differing datatypes in a single column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing to do would be to use pandas inbuilt `pandas.Series.str.match` [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html#pandas-series-str-match). It automatically "skips" int values by casting them all to string.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
                    'Col1': [...],
                    'Col2': [...]}
                 )
df['Col1'].str.match("*pattern*")
```

You can adjust your pattern to make sure that none of your int strings are matched.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={
                    'Col1': ["a string", "a second string", 123, 456, "another string"],
                    'Col2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
                 )
>>> df['Col1'].str.match("[^0-9]+")
0    True
1    True
2     NaN
3     NaN
4    True
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Note that `match` [relies on `re.match`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.1/pandas/core/strings.py#L643) that only anchors the match at the start of the string. To make it match the whole input, add `\Z` at the end of the  pattern.